# Who are the Kullabiyah?

Tags: history, aqidah, theology, sects

I've read a few articles with statement of ibn Taymiyyah pointing at a further sects of creed beside the Salafi, Ash'ary and Maturidi which claim to be part of ahl as-Sunna wal Jama'a (or at least derived from them) against the Mu'tazilah. One among these is the sect of al-Kullabiyah -in reference to the sunni theologian [ibn Kullaab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Kullab) ابن كُلاَّب‎

One may read for example in Maju' al-Fatawa مجموع الفتاوى (when talking about Allah's speech and the qur'an after explaining the view and interpretation of ibn al-Kullab on whether or not the qur'an is the word of Allah) explaining how a group that partially agreed with ibn Kullaab acted in some disputes:
 <sup>In the following I'm translating from Arabic language, as these translations are of my own take them carefully.</sup>

> فَصَارَ قَوْلُ هَؤُلَاءِ مُرَكَّبًا مِنْ قَوْلِ الْمُعْتَزِلَةِ وَقَوْلِ **الْكُلَّابِيَة** فَإِذَا نَاظَرُوا الْمُعْتَزِلَةَ عَلَى أَنَّ الْقُرْآنَ كَلَامُ اللَّهِ غَيْرُ مَخْلُوقٍ نَاظَرُوهُمْ بِطَرِيقَةِ **ابْنِ كُلَّابٍ** وَإِذَا نَاظَرَهُمْ **الْكُلَّابِيَة** عَلَى أَنَّ الْقُرْآنَ الْعَرَبِيَّ كَلَامُ اللَّهِ وَأَنَّ الْقُرْآنَ الَّذِي يَقْرَأهُ الْمُسْلِمُونَ كَلَامُ اللَّهِ نَاظَرُوهُمْ بِحُجَجِ الْمُعْتَزِلَةِ.
> These words became a composite of the words Mu'tazila and telling **Al-Kullabiyah** if they dispute with the Mu'tazila that the Qur'an is the word of Allah and was not created. They would use for this dispute the way of **ibn Kullaab** and if they dispute with **al-Kullabiyah** on the subject that the Arabic Q'uran is the word of Allah and the Qur'an, which Muslims read is the word of Allah they would use arguments of al-Mu'tazila.
> ([Source](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7289/8699))

As I've never heard about this sect before I'd be happy if somebody could shed some light on it, its major principals, creed and history.
At least it seem to me that this sect does no more exist.
Ibn Taymiyyah in fact also quoted much more sects that I've never heard about.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out more about the great scholar of the Salaf, Ibn Kullāb, may Allāh be pleased with him here:

https://asharis.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/imam-ibn-kullab-sunni-theologian-from-the-salaf/

There were many others from the Salaf from this time period who had similar views, such as:

Imām Karabisi

https://asharis.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/imam-al-karabisi/

Hārith Al-Muhāsibī:

https://asharis.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/imam-al-harith-al-muhasibi/

May Allāh be pleased with them all.

Comment: It is not the intent of the site to link elsewhere, an answer rather should display at least a  summary or explanation in your own words of the information linked. See [answer].